# How can I match on, but exclude a regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have this URL:

http://example.com/createSend/step4_1.aspx?cID=876XYZ964D293CF&snap=true&jlkj=kjhkjh&

And this regex pattern:

```
cID=[^&]*
```

Which produces this result:

```
cID=87B6XYZ964D293CF
```

How do I REMOVE the "cID="?

Thanks

Comment: what language? are you working in?

Comment: Which regex parser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.
I'm working in javascript

Answer (score 38):

You can either use lookbehind (not in Javascript):

```
(?<=cID=)[^&]*
```

Or you can use grouping and grab the first group:

```
cID=([^&]*)
```

Answer (score 19):

Generally speaking, to accomplish something like this, you have at least 3 options:

- Use lookarounds, so you can match precisely what you want to capture

  - No lookbehind in Javascript, unfortunately
- Use capturing group to capture specific strings

  - Near universally supported in all flavors
- If all else fails, you can always just take a `substring` of the match

  - Works well if the length of the prefix/suffix to chop is a known constant

#### References

- [w3schools - `jsref` - `substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)
- [regular-expressions.info/Capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

  - [Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

---

#### Examples

Given this test string:

```
i have 35 dogs, 16 cats and 10 elephants
```

These are the matches of some regex patterns:

- `\d+ cats` -> `16 cats` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/UEEwAf6zjQ))
- `\d+(?= cats)` -> `16` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/gkm77p7OFU))
- `(\d+) cats` -> `16 cats` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/Ey6wrLYXNw))

  - Group 1 captures `16`

You can also do multiple captures, for example:

- `(\d+) (cats|dogs)` yields 2 match results ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/b4AIq5CxQP))

  - Result 1: `35 dogs`

    - Group 1 captures `35`
    - Group 2 captures `dogs`
  - Result 2: `16 cats`

    - Group 1 captures `16`
    - Group 2 captures `cats`

Answer (score 9):

With JavaScript, you'll want to use a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (put the part you want to capture inside `()`) in your regular expression

```
var url = 'http://example.com/createSend/step4_1.aspx?cID=876XYZ964D293CF&snap=true&jlkj=kjhkjh&';

var match = url.match(/cID=([^&]*)/);
// ["cID=876XYZ964D293CF", "876XYZ964D293CF"]

// match[0] is the whole pattern
// match[1] is the first capture group - ([^&]*)
// match will be 'false' if the match failed entirely
```

Answer (score 4):

By using capturing groups:

```
cID=([^&]*)
```

and then get $1:

```
87B6XYZ964D293CF
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Javascript code:

```
 var str = "http://example.com/createSend/step4_1.aspx?cID=876XYZ964D293CF&snap=true&jlkj=kjhkjh&";
    var myReg = new RegExp("cID=([^&]*)", "i");
    var myMatch = myReg.exec(str);
    alert(myMatch[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special syntax in javascript which allows you to exclude unwanted match from the result. The syntax is "?:"
In your case the solution would be the following

```
'http://example.com/createSend/step4_1.aspx?cID=876XYZ964D293CF&snap=true&jlkj=kjhkjh&'.match(/(?:cID=+)([^&]*)/)[1];
```

Comment: This is excessive. `'http://example.com/createSend/step4_1.aspx?cID=876XYZ964D293CF&snap=true&jlkj=kjhkjh&'.match(/cID=+([^&]*)/)[1];` is simpler as it does not require the non-capturing group and returns the same result as your example.