# single split or match regex

Tags: c#, regex

9.jul. 3 dni od 205,00 EUR

Is it possible with single regex (match opr split) get 205,00 number from string? It must be single regex and not 2 or 3 regex which give 205,00 as result.

string looks like:

```
 <option value="9.7.2010|3">9.jul. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR <option value="23.7.2010|3">23.jul. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR <option value="27.8.2010|3">27.avg. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR <option value="10.9.2010|3">10.sep. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR <option value="24.9.2010|3">24.sep. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR <option value="29.10.2010|3">29.okt. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR <option value="25.3.2011|3">25.mar. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR <option value="15.4.2011|3">15.apr. 3 dni od 205,00&nbsp;EUR </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible issues here

#### The space

Is it a space (ASCII 32), or `&nbsp;`? Or perhaps it's just any `\s` character?

---

#### The match portion

I'm going to assume that it's just a regular space. If this is not the case, then substitute it in the following pattern.

To match only the numbers portion, you can use `\d+,\d\d(?= EUR)`. This uses lookahead `(?=___)` so you only match the portion that you're interested in.

The other option is to match `(\d+,\d\d) EUR` and then extract [`Groups[1]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

#### Related questions

- [How can I match on, but exclude a regex pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003310/how-can-i-match-on-but-exclude-a-regex-pattern)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: (\d+,\d+)(?=&nbsp;EUR) is what i am looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
(\d+,\d\d) EUR$
```

You didn't really specify what the subject looks like in general.

Comment: i already try similar: (\d+,\d\d)&nbsp;EUR but not working. result is not 205,00

Comment: @senzacionale: what is the result? No match at all? Or `205,00 EUR`?

Comment: hi, no match at all with your regex type. I use  
(\d+,\d+)(?=&nbsp;EUR) ater yor help. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt of `(\d+,\d\d) EUR` (hopefully you weren't actually typing in `&nbsp;`) should work, but you have to access group 1 out of the result to get just what's in the parentheses.  For example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+,\d\d) EUR");
Match match = regex.Match("9.jul. 3 dni od 205,00 EUR");
string cashString = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&nbsp;` will most likely be converted to ASCII 160 (html decoded), which is not the same as space. Using \s+ will match no breaking spaces as well as normal space, tab and line feed/carriage return.

If it's not decoded then you should be able to use `&nbsp;` instead of \s+.

```
(\d+,\d+)\s+EUR
```