# Why doesn't finite repetition in lookbehind work in some flavors?

Tags: c#, java, python, regex, lookbehind

I want to parse the 2 digits in the middle from a date in `dd/mm/yy` format but also allowing single digits for day and month.

This is what I came up with:

```
(?<=^[\d]{1,2}\/)[\d]{1,2}
```

I want a 1 or 2 digit number `[\d]{1,2}` with a 1 or 2 digit number and slash `^[\d]{1,2}\/` before it.

This doesn't work on many combinations, I have tested `10/10/10`, `11/12/13`, etc...

But to my surprise `(?<=^\d\d\/)[\d]{1,2}` worked.

But the `[\d]{1,2}` should also match if `\d\d` did, or am I wrong?

Comment: I use C# but tested the above regex on a web regex tester. I didn't know there are such significant differences in the different languages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### On lookbehind support

Major regex flavors have varying supports for lookbehind differently; some imposes certain restrictions, and some doesn't even support it at all.

- Javascript: not supported
- Python: fixed length only
- Java: finite length only
- .NET: no restriction

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

---

### Python

In Python, where only fixed length lookbehind is supported, your original pattern raises an error because `\d{1,2}` obviously does not have a fixed length. You can "fix" this by alternating on two different fixed-length lookbehinds, e.g. something like this:

```
(?<=^\d\/)\d{1,2}|(?<=^\d\d\/)\d{1,2}
```

Or perhaps you can put both lookbehinds as alternates of a non-capturing group:

```
(?:(?<=^\d\/)|(?<=^\d\d\/))\d{1,2}
```

(note that you can just use `\d` without the brackets).

That said, it's probably much simpler to use a capturing group instead:

```
^\d{1,2}\/(\d{1,2})
```

Note that [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) returns what group 1 captures if you only have one group. Capturing group is more widely supported than lookbehind, and often leads to a more readable pattern (such as in this case).

This snippet illustrates all of the above points:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=^\d\/)|(?<=^\d\d\/))\d{1,2}')

print(p.findall("12/34/56"))   # "[34]"
print(p.findall("1/23/45"))    # "[23]"

p = re.compile(r'^\d{1,2}\/(\d{1,2})')

print(p.findall("12/34/56"))   # "[34]"
print(p.findall("1/23/45"))    # "[23]"

p = re.compile(r'(?<=^\d{1,2}\/)\d{1,2}')
# raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [Capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

### Java

Java supports only finite-length lookbehind, so you can use `\d{1,2}` like in the original pattern. This is demonstrated by the following snippet:

```
    String text =
        "12/34/56 date\n" +
        "1/23/45 another date\n";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)(?<=^\\d{1,2}/)\\d{1,2}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    } // "34", "23"
```

Note that `(?m)` is the embedded [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) so that `^` matches the start of every line. Note also that since `\` is an escape character for string literals, you must write `"\\"` to get one backslash in Java.

---

### C-Sharp

C# supports full regex on lookbehind. The following snippet shows how you can use `+` repetition on a lookbehind:

```
var text = @"
1/23/45
12/34/56
123/45/67
1234/56/78
";

Regex r = new Regex(@"(?m)(?<=^\d+/)\d{1,2}");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(text)) {
  Console.WriteLine(m);
} // "23", "34", "45", "56"
```

Note that unlike Java, in C# you can use [@-quoted string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.80%29.aspx) so that you don't have to escape `\`.

For completeness, here's how you'd use the capturing group option in C#:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?m)^\d+/(\d{1,2})");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(text)) {
  Console.WriteLine("Matched [" + m + "]; month = " + m.Groups[1]);
}
```

Given the previous `text`, this prints:

```
Matched [1/23]; month = 23
Matched [12/34]; month = 34
Matched [123/45]; month = 45
Matched [1234/56]; month = 56
```

#### Related questions

- [How can I match on, but exclude a regex pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003310/how-can-i-match-on-but-exclude-a-regex-pattern/)

Comment: I got a positive look-behind with a `+` repetition to work on Java 11. `"a 111x b111x c".replaceFirst("(?<=b1+)x", "z")` gave `a 111x b111z c`. I don’t know if it’s an improvement in some Java version.

Answer (score 4):

Unless there's a specific reason for using the lookbehind which isn't noted in the question, how about simply matching the whole thing and only capturing the bit you're interested in instead?

JavaScript example:

```
>>> /^\d{1,2}\/(\d{1,2})\/\d{1,2}$/.exec("12/12/12")[1]
"12"
```

Answer (score 3):

To quote [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> The bad news is that most regex
>   flavors do not allow you to use just
>   any regex inside a lookbehind, because
>   they cannot apply a regular expression
>   backwards. Therefore, the regular
>   expression engine needs to be able to
>   figure out how many steps to step back
>   before checking the lookbehind.
>
> Therefore, many regex flavors,
>   including those used by Perl and
>   Python, only allow fixed-length
>   strings. You can use any regex of
>   which the length of the match can be
>   predetermined. This means you can use
>   literal text and character classes.
>   You cannot use repetition or optional
>   items. You can use alternation, but
>   only if all options in the alternation
>   have the same length.

In other words your regex does not work because you're using a variable-width expression inside a lookbehind and your regex engine does not support that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to those listed by @polygenelubricants, there are two more exceptions to the "fixed length only" rule.  In PCRE (the regex engine for PHP, Apache, *et al*) and Oniguruma (Ruby 1.9, Textmate), a lookbehind may consist of an alternation in which each alternative may match a different number of characters, as long as the length of each alternative is fixed.  For example:

```
(?<=\b\d\d/|\b\d/)\d{1,2}(?=/\d{2}\b)
```

Note that the alternation has to be at the top level of the lookbehind subexpression.  You might, like me, be tempted to factor out the common elements, like this:

```
(?<=\b(?:\d\d/|\d)/)\d{1,2}(?=/\d{2}\b)
```

...but it wouldn't work; at the top level, the subexpression now consists of a single alternative with a non-fixed length.

The second exception is much more useful: `\K`, supported by Perl and PCRE.  It effectively means "pretend the match really started here."  Whatever appears before it in the regex is treated as a positive lookbehind.  As with .NET lookbehinds, there are no restrictions; whatever can appear in a normal regex can be used before the `\K`.

```
\b\d{1,2}/\K\d{1,2}(?=/\d{2}\b)
```

But most of the time, when someone has a problem with lookbehinds, it turns out they shouldn't even be using them.  As @insin pointed out, this problem can be solved much more easily by using a capturing group.

**EDIT:** Almost forgot JGSoft, the regex flavor used by EditPad Pro and PowerGrep; like .NET, it has completely unrestricted lookbehinds, positive and negative.