# two question about python regular expressions

Tags: c#, python, regex

Q1. why we can not use word boundary and back reference without using `r` at start of regex?
e.g. `'\b[a-z]{5}\d{3}\b'` this not works but this `r'\b[a-z]{5}\d{3}\b'` works

Q2. why python does not support `variable length negative look behind assertions` while it supports `variable length negative look ahead assertion`, `c#` support both and i think it is an excellent feature to have also `variable length negative look behind` in `python`.

please clear these two concepts. thanks

Comment: Q1: replace '\b' with '\\b' within your regex and it will work without raw string

Comment: Regarding the second, the answer is probably "Because".

Comment: don't ask two question in one posting, don't ask questions that cannot really be answered.

Comment: @Hop He didn't know the question couldn't really be answered. The questions are also closely related, I think they're perfectly appropriate for one question.

Comment: @agf: 1) now he knows. 2) the questions are not related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work without raw strings:

```
'\\b[a-z]{5}\\d{3}\\b'
```

You just need to double escape the special chars (actually, what you do is escape all backslashes).

Variable length assertions are one of those features that some implementations support and some don't. Check out the [regex module on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) for a version with more features and better unicode support, which may eventually replace the standard library `re`.

Edit: To make the version from your comment work without raw strings, use:

```
re.sub('[a-z]+(\d+)', '\\1', string)
```

Again, Python interprets backslashes. it thinks `\1` means a byte value of `1`. If you actually mean `\1`, you need to escape the backslash by doing `\\1`, or use raw strings.

Edit 2: Adding the link from @Nate's comment to the [list of Python escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: so raw string is basically escaping special characters?? so why back refrencing dont work? e.g. this dont work `re.sub('[a-z](\d+)', '\1', string)` but this works `re.sub('[a-z]+(\d+)', r'\1', string)`

Comment: I've added the example from your comment to my answer.

Comment: @agf - Not **strictly** true; I'm pretty sure python only replaces the escape sequences in [this list](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (though I only just checked a couple).  Not that I'm trying to confuse Aamir - please, use raw strings - but the language doesn't require it for all escape sequences.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was generalizing. It doesn't hurt to be consistent and escape all backslashes. He has already noticed that `\d` works fine.

Comment: @agf: this is issue with only word boundary, so when you can use `\w+` or `\d+` without explicitly defining `r` at start then why we dont double escape the `\w+`??

Comment: Yes, as @Nate said, some of them will work. See the link in his comment which I've added to my post. However, it will __never hurt__ to escape backslashes, so if you're not using raw strings, you should __always__ do it, instead of just where necessary, or you might miss one where it's required.

Comment: @agf: @nate: and what about `variable length look behind`? why python does not support that?

Comment: I already answered that in my answer -- no particular reason, Python's `re` module isn't that great. I linked to the more advanced `regex` module in my answer, which has many more features, and may replace `re` eventually.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your first question, this is because the `r` designates a "raw string".  Without this `r`, your backslashes are interpreted as escape codes.  If you don't want to use raw strings, you can use `'\\b[a-z]{5}\\d{3}\\b'`, although this is far less readable.  You can read more detail about [raw strings here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings).

In regards to your second question, you should take a look at [this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159524/why-doesnt-finite-repetition-in-lookbehind-work-in-some-flavorsp), which discusses the differences between various flavors of regular expression used by different languages (namely C#, Java, and Python).

Answer (score 0):

Almost all information you can find in [tutorial - which is your the best friend](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=re.findall#module-re):

> Regular expressions use the backslash character ('\') to indicate
>   special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
>   invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of
>   the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for
>   example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write '\\'
>   as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be \, and
>   each backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string
>   literal.
>
> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string
>   containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string
>   containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
>   code using this raw string notation.

It is quite hard to answer on your second question - i think that authors are implementing only those features which they think are required. They try to add code that is useful for the most of user but it is impossible to implement all the features fast.