# Regular expression to find the arguments in a function call

Tags: regex

I need to extract the arguments from a function Say, Function_1(arg1,agr2,....argn).

Is it possible to strip the arguments alone with out brackets.

I tried using `\([\w,]*\)` expression

Comment: I assume you want to parse the source code somehow?

Comment: Argument, as in passed to a function call, OR is it parameter of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "catch" the matches you need to put braces around them:

```
 \(([\w,]*)\)
```

This way you will find everything `arg1,arg2` in `$1`.

Comment: Yeah.. much simpler , u will get it in the first group.

Answer (score 1):

use this Regular Expression `(?<=[\w]*\()[\w,]*(?=\))` to solve the purpose

Comment: What language have you tested this on?

Comment: The answer is using variable-width look-behind, which is only supported in C#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159524/why-doesnt-finite-repetition-in-lookbehind-work-in-some-flavorsp