# Match all "http" only URLs without additional characters

Tags: regex, screen-scraping

I have tried the below expressions.

```
(http:\/\/.*?)['\"\< \>]


(http:\/\/[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\"]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|\"])
```

The first one is doing well but always gives the last extra character with the matched URLs.

Eg:

```
http://domain.com/path.html" 

http://domain.com/path.html<
```

Notice

```
" <
```

I don't want them with URLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use lookahead instead of making `['\"\< >]` part of your match, i.e.:

```
(http:\/\/.*?)(?=['\"\< >])
```

Generally speaking, whereas `ab` matches `ab`, `a(?=b)` matches `a` (if it's followed by `b`).

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

#### Related questions

- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)

---

#### Capturing group option

Lookarounds are not supported by all flavors. More widely supported are capturing groups.

Generally speaking, whereas `(a)b` still matches `ab`, it also captures `a` in group 1.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Round Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

#### Related questions

- [How can I match on, but exclude a regex pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003310/how-can-i-match-on-but-exclude-a-regex-pattern/)

---

#### Negated character class option

Depending on the need, often times using a negated character class is much better than using a reluctant `.*?` (followed by a lookahead to assert the terminator pattern in this case).

Let's consider the problem of matching "everything between `A` and `ZZ`". As it turns out, this specification is ambiguous: we will come up with 3 patterns that does this, and they will yield different matches. Which one is "correct" depends on the expectation, which is not properly conveyed in the original statement.

We use the following as input:

```
eeAiiZooAuuZZeeeZZfff
```

We use 3 different patterns:

- `A(.*)ZZ` yields 1 match: `AiiZooAuuZZeeeZZ` ([as seen on ideone.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/IlA7Gh4q9X))

  - This is the *greedy* variant; group 1 matched and captured `iiZooAuuZZeee`
- `A(.*?)ZZ` yields 1 match: `AiiZooAuuZZ` ([as seen on ideone.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/As1IQquu1C))

  - This is the *reluctant* variant; group 1 matched and captured `iiZooAuu`
- `A([^Z]*)ZZ` yields 1 match: `AuuZZ` ([as seen on ideone.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/zyHHYQIxe6))

  - This is the *negated character class* variant; group 1 matched and captured `uu`

Here's a visual representation of what they matched:

```
         ___n
        /   \              n = negated character class
eeAiiZooAuuZZeeeZZfff      r = reluctant
  \_________/r   /         g = greedy
   \____________/g
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Repetition: An Alternative to Laziness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Because believe me, if I have to go an extra mile or two, I will.

Comment: Huh? Makes no sense for this to be downvoted and not the other (at the time) very similar lookahead question, which came after. Well, assuming the downvote was cast before the boat picture was added. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "(?=*regex*)" (lookahead), which lookups a particular pattern, but doesn't include it in the result:

```
http:\/\/.*?(?=['\"\< >])
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I'd probably do this simply by saying "keep going until you get an unwanted character", like so:

```
http://[^'"< >]*
```

Escaped version (based on Q - not sure what engine this is):

```
http:\/\/[^'\"\< >]*
```

However the [lookahead solution by polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237003/improving-regular-expression-to-match-all-http-only-urls-very-neatly/3237062#3237062) is a more flexible way, if you might have some of those characters in the URL (but not at the end).

Comment: +1; whenever applicable, negated charclass is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Hey Peter, congratulations back on reaching 10k! :)

Comment: Thanks Tim. :) And thanks to poly for the vote which took me over the milestone. :)