# Regex match within parens

Tags: javascript, regex

There are a lot of questions on SO re: matching within a brackets, parens, etc but I'm wondering how to match within a character (parens) while ignoring that character

```
"Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists".match(/\(([^)]+)\)/g)
// => ["(email)", "(basil@gmail.com)"]
```

I believe this is because JS doesn't support `[^)]`. Given that, how would you recommend extracting the values within the parens.

I'd prefer something less hacky than having to call `.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')` on the values

I'd like the return value to be `["email", "basil@gmail.com"]`

Comment: [^)] is not a look behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Extract text between *braces ()* not returning *braces*

using this two banally simple examples:

## Using `.match()` to extract and construct the Array

```js
var arr = "Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists".match(/(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))/g);

console.log( arr );
```

https://regex101.com/r/gjDhSC/1
[MDN - String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

---

## Using `.replace()` to extract values and push to Array

```js
var arr=[];

"Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists"
    .replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, (p1, p2) => arr.push(p2) );

console.log( arr );
```

https://regex101.com/r/gjDhSC/2
[MDN - String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: `/\((.+?)\)/ig.exec("Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists")` == `["(email)", "email"]` in the chrome console?

Comment: both of those still include the parens when run in chrome console

Comment: @pherris - you've hit the nail on the head.  Have credited you in my answer.  (I added a loop to gather all the results.)

Comment: By far the most compact and efficient solution

Comment: @pherris ? Simply don't use `exec` or it's brother `match` cause than you need to exhaust till `null` inside a `while` - Instead use `replace()` for fun and profit.

Comment: "I prefer something less hacks than...", then accepts it lol!

Answer (score 2):

See here: [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Combine with @pherris' comment:

```
var str = "Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists";
var rx = /\((.+?)\)/ig;
match = rx.exec(str);
alert(match[1]);
while (match !== null) {
   match = rx.exec(str);
   alert(match[1]);
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/60p9zg89/  (will generate popups)

---

This executes the regex multiple times, returning the captured string (in the brackets).

Pushing an alert to the browser isn't very useful, you specified returning an array - so:

```
function rxGroups(rx, str) {
   var matches = new Array();
   match = rx.exec(str);
   while (match != null) {
      matches.push(match[1]);
      match = rx.exec(str);
   }
   return matches;
}

var x = rxGroups(
   /\((.+?)\)/ig,
   "Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists"
);

alert(x.join('\n'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/60p9zg89/1/

Comment: I just re-read your question, and noticed you want an array returned.  I'll adjust appropriately.

Comment: Adjusted to include returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

You may be wanting the result of the first capture group.  After your match you can get the first group:

```
(function(s, x) {
 return s.match(x)
    .map(function(m) {
      var f = m.match(x);
      return RegExp.$1;
    });
})('Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists', /\(([^()]+)\)/g)
```

Result = ["email", "basil@gmail.com"]

Comment: Don't know why you down voted this.  It's a widely accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003310/how-can-i-match-on-but-exclude-a-regex-pattern ... good luck to you.

Comment: agreed - +1 from me, it works.  Arguably cleaner than my solution too (performance of the anonymous function and .map is pretty efficient I'd assume?)

Comment: I don't know how performant the code is, actually.  It seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: And despite almost every browser supporting it, Perl-style $1..$9 are not officially part of ecma.

Comment: One would hope they continue to standardise such shortcuts/improvements for regex in it though - with more power in the local browsers (as we move yet again away from thin client/fat servers and into fat client / thin servers) there is a lot of obvious justification for it.

Comment: I'm thinking the poster is gaming this post for rep anyway and I'm pretty sure the question is a dupe to boot.

Comment: @KrisOye I wasn't the one who downvoted and think asking a question for rep is ridiculous. You're right, people have asked this question but in the time I spent researching, couldn't find one that worked and had the result I wanted without parens. I appreciate your answer but accepted a different answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Key (email)=(basil@gmail.com) already exists";
var matches = [];
str.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, function(g0,g1){matches.push(g1);})
```

Comment: How does your answer **adds any more value** [over this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33661944/383904)?

Comment: It does not. I just dont know how to mark this question has already answered

Comment: Ok will try it. On my cel !!