# Regex: match, but do not include in groups

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have some objects like this:

```
"unit":{
          "id":"1",
          "title":"I am a title",
          "description":" description",
          "category":{
            "name":"Reading",
            "type":"READING",
            "icon":"fas fa-book"
}
```

I'd like to remove the double quotes from the keys. Is there a good way to do this in regex? I use: `".*":` to match the key's, but am unsure of how to do the partial replace in VSCode. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003310/how-can-i-match-on-but-exclude-a-regex-pattern), but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Try `"([^"]+)":` and replace with `$1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
"([^"]+)":
```

Replace with `$1:`. *Details*:

- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"]+)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to the this group value): any one or more chars other than `"`
- `":` - a `":` string.